# Is it better to use putExtra and getExtra's or use a public getter method?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I came up with this question because I realized that I'm currently doing both in my program and both methods work.

For transfer of the value of an integer timeToUse from my activity to my service, I am using `putExtra` to store the value in my intent and then `getIntExtra` in my service to pull the value from intent.

For the transfer of the value of a `boolean notificationSounds` from my activity to my service, I am calling a method that returns the context of my activity, then using the context to call a getter method that returns the value.

Are either of these methods better/safer than the other? Why?

Comment: If you can omit a Context as parameter pass, then you should.

Comment: Any tips on how to do that with a service that is already running? Can I just replace the value if I have to change it by using putExtra again with the same key string? @stealthjong

Comment: Why not do with the boolean exactly as you did with the integer?

Comment: @stealthjong because the integer is a one-time selection variable for the user and becomes constant, the boolean needs to be updated when the user selects on/off for notification sounds in the gui which can happen at any time

Comment: Ok, and now with code. What kind of service do you have? What code have you written? Why don't you just use a getter and setter for your boolean in your service? If you can pass a Context, why not a boolean?

Comment: @stealthjong HAH good point, im tired. Just curious, why should I strive to omit a context as a parameter pass? What makes it unwanted?

Comment: The more you pass the context around, the greater the chance that a reference to the context is kept. And when that happens, the GC can't clean the activity up, because it's still referenced. And that can cause memory leaks. So be careful when passing around contexts